# How to extract DNA sequence from browser track input files (BigWig, bed etc.) files

Tags: r, python, chip-seq, atac-seq, macs2

A BigWig file for something like Chip-seq, or ATAC data has the following format for each line i:

chrom_i - start_i - end_i - value_i

[image]

I need to convert for each line the (start_i -> end_i) reference to the actual DNA sequence 'ATATCCTAG...' so that at the end I have a list of DNA sequences like 'ATATCCTAG...' and the Chip-seq activity value associated with that sequence segment. What are the ways to do this? For example, what tool(s) can I use to generate the (sequence, value) pairs from browser tracks for the Chip-seq or ATAC etc. And in fact, going from BigWig browser track files for Chip-seq the most direct way to produce this kind of (seq,value) data? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the link.][1]. Instructions are very clear at the website
[1]: https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/getfasta.html

Comment: Ah, perfect @Supertech! Thank  you, both answers helpful... the link included here is the exact answer I was looking for: bedtools getfasta converts index range start_index-end_index into it's equivalent sequence of nucleotides indicated in the input *.fa file. I just need to figure out how to create the "fa" file for an entire genome like mm10, where it's usually in chromosomal chunks (i.e. Chr2.fa).

Comment: I believe each chromosome is independently numbered. If you want to generate a single genome file with all the chromosomes, download individual chromosomes and simply concatenate them. For example using Linux command "cat". >cat chr1.fa chr2.fa ...

Comment: It looks like they may have single file. I have not downloaded to check it though. It has been long that I did not work with mouse genome. http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/mm10/bigZips/

Comment: Yes, I am trying to think why/how that would work: I guess the *.fa file has the chrX indicator at each line which would be matched along with the index (I assume a complete index needs to include chromosome number as well)! Thank you again.

Comment: Try samtools faidx. Check bedtools manual. https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/general-usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Bedtools can take a list of coordinates and a fasta and return a multifasta of the specified regions.